# How does the rate of change of momentum due to unsteady flow inside a control volume not always equal 0 due to momentum conservation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, momentum, aerodynamics

I apologize for the bad title, I am struggling to shorten the question; essentially, in J.D.Andersons *Fundamentals of aerodynamics*, there is a section where he derives the momentum equations. Starting with the classic $F = d(mv)/dt$ and uses a fixed finite volume frame, everything makes sense (reasonably) until he mentions that the total rate of change of momentum of the fluid as it sweeps through the control volume is equal to: the net flow out the control volume + the rate of change of momentum "due to unsteady flow fluctuations" inside the control volume.

Now I always thought momentum is conserved and so the momentum leaving is precisely the momentum it had entering the control volume + the momentum by the force imparted on the fluid (from body and surface forces as described in the book), so I really struggle to understand the second term/addition (the rate of momentum inside). How can this be possible to just magically have momentum in the volume but is not flowing out, and whats that to do with a time varying unsteady flow?

Answer (score 1):

Real fluids have, among other things, viscous dissipation.  If you imagine pipe flow from left to right, even in a very wide pipe where we are ignoring effects of the walls, the fluid inside a small control volume is constantly encountering internal friction of the molecules sliding past one another. This is constantly robbing the fluid of momentum and converting it to directionless kinetic energy that heats the fluid up slightly. So in a control volume cube near the center of a pipe, the momentum entering is indeed less than the momentum exiting.

Comment: That definitely makes sense thankyou. Although it states its for non steady state fluid specifically, there was an example question which specifically removed this term in the equation because it was steady state, but was still viscous (giving rise to your question). Unless i read the book wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The rate of change of momentum within the control volume for an unsteady flow is equal to the momentum flow rate in minus the momentum out plus the surface forces acting on the fluid within the control volume.  There are also pressure forces at the inlet and outlet that should included.